# Why do I get noSuchElementException when using listIterator.add()?

Tags: java, iterator, addition, nosuchelementexception

Without further delay, I will post my code straight away. It is very simple so you shouldn't find any problems understanding it. My idea is to `add` **color** after it found **"blue"** using `listIterator`. Apparently there is something wrong here.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Color c1 = new Color("red");
        Color c2 = new Color("blue");
        Color c3 = new Color("green");

        List<Color> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);

        ListIterator<Color> iterator = list.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
            if (iterator.next().tone.equals("blue")){
                iterator.add(new Color("yellow"));
            }
        }

    }
}

class Color {
    String tone;

    public Color(String tone) {
        this.tone = tone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tone;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
red
green
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:999)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `hasNext()` once for 2 calls of `next()`. Call it once and save it to be able to use multiple times

```
while (iterator.hasNext()){
     Color current = iterator.next();
     System.out.println(current);
     if (current.tone.equals("blue")){
         iterator.add(new Color("yellow"));
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks azro! Could you help me understand the name of that exception `noSuchElement`? Because `next()` technically didn't remove my **element**, it just moved the cursor.

Comment: @Stefan "Hi I want the next element please", "Sorry there no such one in my actual iterator" there no "next" element from the position we are now, all the ones have be consumed

Comment: True, I finally get it :) Although `.next()` is in if loop, it is still calling `next()`. That is what you are saying? So eventually in last call there will be no more elements and I call `next()`. Right?

Comment: @Stefan Yes the `.next()` in the if DOES move the cursor forward, each call of next() does, so with hasNext you're sure that you can do 1 move, but you were doing 2

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is provided but posting if it helps
refer below code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Color c1 = new Color("red");
    Color c2 = new Color("blue");
    Color c3 = new Color("green");

    List<Color> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c2);
    list.add(c3);

    ListIterator<Color> iterator = list.listIterator();
    System.out.println(iterator.next());//-->red
    System.out.println(iterator.next());//-->blue
    System.out.println(iterator.next());//-->green
    System.out.println(iterator.next());//-->java.util.NoSuchElementException (iterator is moved forward but list is exhausted)
}
```

so basically `iterator.next()` locates the element in the iterable collection.
hence calling `iterator.next()` multiple time in ur `while` loop will shift the cursor eveytime to next value , hence its better to store  `iterator.next()` into a variable inside the loop.